# vim: Marks getting deleted/lost

Tags: vim

I've tried to find an answer to this on the googles, but been unsuccessful. *The problem is this:*

In vim I delete a line that contained a mark; so I guess the mark is also deleted.  Now I can't jump back to that location any more.  I'm coding so there is a lot of line deleting going on.  It's a pain having to manually find the place that I set the mark again.

Is there a way around this?  I want vim to jump to aprox the same location where the mark used to be.  Either the same line number, or the closest guess.

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay. The other thread says to **use uppercase marks**. This seems to work well.  A small pain to remember to do this, but this is definitely useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `. which is a position of the last change occurred in the current buffer. Then you can mark it again.